# Rewrite ajax request and the values returned

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need help to write this without the `async: false,`.

```
var imageX;
var groupX;
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'php/myphp.php',
    dataType:'json',
    async: false,

    success: function(response){
            imageX = response[0].studentName,
    groupX = response[0].subjectId;
            alertImageX();
            }
});
function alertImageX() {
(function() {
    var image = { 
        'back': { 'url':imageX, 'img':null },
        'front': { 'url':'img/bg.jpg', 'img':null }
    };
```

php

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT studentName, subjectId FROM grade3 WHERE eligible = ? LIMIT 1');
$array = array('Yes');
$query->execute($array);
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: I want to be able to get the data that is returned by the AJAX call (i.e.: imageX). And avoid `async: false,` coz is bad practice.

Comment: in the success response is where the data is, can we see the PHP code along with the AJAX code?

Answer (score 1):

`"async: false"` should not be needed in this situation because your response is already processed after AJAX request is complete, as it is placed inside the "success" element. Sorry if I missed any detail

**EDIT:**

Sorry I just read your comment regarding what you want to achieve. The `response` variable contains whatever the script called by AJAX echoed (in case of a PHP script), so you basically need to echo what you want the script to return and access that through the `response` variable.

Comment: In other words, your code should work as-is, without async: false.

Comment: But when I remove `async: false` the code doesn't work.

Comment: @NathaliaZeed Move your logic in to the `success` handler

Comment: pass the imageX and groupX through the function

Comment: right after the success function add a alert(response); and tell us what you are getting for the PHP response

Comment: There's a syntax error if I add it right after the `function success: function(response){ .... } alert(response);`

Comment: But if I add it below the `function success: function(response){` line the Alert shows [object Object]

Comment: any suggestions please?

Comment: @NathaliaZeed `console.log(response);`